# Is final used for optimization in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-optimization, virtual, final

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void f() final override { };
};

int main() {
    B* b = new B();
    b->f();
}
```

In this case, is the compiler required to still do the v-table lookup for `b->f();`, or can it call `B::f()` directly because it was marked `final`?

Comment: `class C : pubic A { void f() override; };`

Comment: `new A()` is ill-formed, because `A` is abstract.

Comment: Look at *devirtualization*.

Comment: BTW, optimization are not required by the standard. There is the as-if rule which allows optimization.

Comment: Try e.g. `class C : public B { void f() override {} };`, and see what happens.

Comment: The code you wrote in main is so simply that the compiler knows the target of the pointer and it can call the function directly, maybe also inlined as well. But yes, final is used in gcc to get better optimization. BUT: If you do not really know that nobody wants to derive from your class and overwrite some functionality, avoid final.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> Is final used for optimization in C++?

It can be, and is.

As noted, it is being used already; [see here](https://godbolt.org/g/f02eYq) and [here](https://godbolt.org/g/ASLk4B) showing the generated code for the override with and without `final`.

[An optimisation along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36898879/3747990) would relate to the "de-virtualization" of the virtual calls. This is not always immediately affected by the `final` of the class nor method. Albeit they offer help to determine this, the normal rules of the virtual functions and class hierarchy apply.

If the compiler can determine that at runtime a particular method will always be called (e.g. given the OP example, with an automatic object), it could apply such [an optimisation anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7047248/3747990), irrespective of whether the method is `final` or not.

Optimisations fall under the [*as-if rule*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), that allow the compiler to apply any transformation so long as the observable behaviour is as-if the original code had been executed.

Comment: This has been the answer for a long time, but is any compiler /actually/ using final for devirtualization?

Comment: @JohanLundberg: Quick experimentation with the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/f02eYq) and locally shows that at least gcc 6.1, clang 3.8 and MSVC++2015U2 use the `final` keyword for devirtualization.

Comment: For anyone curious I think this is where this optimization currently happens in clang: [CodeGenFunction::CanDevirtualizeMemberFunctionCall](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/0e2d28ae3ba7407eb4c0b777f63e237013608261/lib/CodeGen/CGClass.cpp#L2676)

Comment: @JohanJundberg There is an excellent blog serious from one of the gcc developers about devirtualization: http://hubicka.blogspot.de/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html. It also contains an explanation when final helps, and gcc introduced a warning for cases where adding `final`would enable optimizations which cannot be done otherwise.